# ADB unable to start or find devices after sudo adb devices

Tags: android, linux, docker, adb

I am currently trying to get a docker container to connect to my android devices over ADB. ADB is able to see that a device is connected but is unable to get the required permissions to access the desired device.

Normally I would fix this very quickly by running a simple adb kill-server followed by a sudo adb-devices. Unfortunately a sudo adb devices does not recognize that any device is attached. If i try to do a adb devices any time after the sudo command was executed I run into the following error:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
cannot bind 'local:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

After this point even if I run another kill-server I receive the same error on adb devices requests. In order to get past this I have to manually delete the socket /tmp/5037 generated by the request.

At this point my main goal is just to get access to the ADB device I am attempting to test with. Is there some step that I am missing that might be causing this weird behavior?

### For reference:

- usb debugging is enabled and I am able to adb into the device from
  the box with the docker container running on it.
- I do make sure to run an adb kill-server on the box with the
  container in it before running adb start server inside the container.

device as listed by lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 0c2e:0ba1 android_device_name
```

99-android.rules entry in /etc/udev/:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0c2e", GROUP="plugdev" MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="0c2e",SYMLINK+="android_adb"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="0c2e",SYMLINK+="android_fastboot"
```

my adb_usb.ini

```
0x067e
0x0c2e
0x05c6
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable USB debugging in your phone. On your phone go to

- Settings
- General
- Developer Options
- USB debugging

In Android 4.2 and higher versions, the Developer Options menu and USB Debugging option have been hidden. In former 4.X versions of Android, USB Debugging option is under Developer Options menu.
First, you need to enable "Developer Options Menu".

Click Menu button to enter into App drawer.
Go to "Settings".
Scroll down to the bottom and tap "About phone" or "About tablet",
Scroll down to the bottom of the "About phone" and locate the "Build Number" field.

Tap the Build number field seven times to enable Developer Options. Tap a few times and you'll see a countdown that reads "You are now 3 steps away from being a developer."
When you are done, you'll see the message "You are now a developer!".
Tap the Back button and you'll see the Developer options menu under System on your Settings screen.
Now, you can enable USB Debugging mode.

Go to Settings>Developer Options>USB Debugging. Tap the USB Debugging checkbox.

Comment: Unfortunately usb debugging is already enabled. I can adb shell into the device when outside of the docker container but after doing a adb kill-server  outside the container and a adb start server inside the container, the container is still unable to get the required permissions to access the device.

Comment: did you try restarting your device and your computer? and retry

Comment: I restarted and reconnected the device. The computer part is a bit tricky since its a docker container so restarting either saves or wipes all progress since the last save state.